# gcc fails to compile static function in namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, g++

I have the following declaration.

```
namespace test{
static cl_option* find_opt(const int &val, const cl_option *options);
}

test::cl_option* test::find_opt(const int &val, cl_option *options){}
```

The problem is when compiling I get the following error.

```
error: ‘test::cl_option* test::find_opt(const int&, test::cl_option*)’ should have been declared inside ‘test’
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function you declared is different from the one you tried to define: the second parameter is "const" in the declaration, and not in the definition. Those are two different functions.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have different signatures of the declaration and definition (the second argument being a const pointer versus non-const pointer). The compiler expected you to declare the non-const version inside the `test` namespace, but it can't find it (it only finds the declaration with a const pointer).

static functions in namespaces works fine. This builds in GCC 4.0.1:

```
namespace test {
   struct B {};
   static B* a();
}

test::B* test::a() {}

int main() { return 0;}
```